# Increase space between text lines in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, line-spacing

How do I increase the spacing between two lines (or leading) in a paragraph in Photoshop?

Comment: What OS, what version of Photoshop? It would help if you would be more specific, like the tool you're using or post a screenshot

Comment: Also, since your question was migrated here, you should create your account on this site, and associate it with your Stack Overflow account, to regain ownership over your question.

Answer (score 27):

From [this link](http://www.adobe.com/designcenter/photoshop/articles/phscs2at_typography_05.html):

> There are two types of formatting:
>   Character (which can apply to one or
>   more characters) and Paragraph (which
>   always applies to one or more
>   paragraphs). You can find these
>   settings in the Options bar (when the
>   Text tool is selected in the Tool
>   palette) or in the Character and
>   Paragraph palettes.

[image: formatting]

> Leading (“ledding”) determines the
>   amount of space between lines in a
>   paragraph. (...) If you want the leading to
>   be consistent throughout a paragraph,
>   you should either select every
>   character in the paragraph before you
>   set the leading in the Character
>   palette, or you should apply the
>   leading while the text layer is
>   selected in the Layers palette (but no
>   text on the layer is selected).

Comment: Darn you beat me to it! I thought you weren't motivated to gain rep anymore?!? ;-)

Comment: Never lose an occasion to put freehand circles.

Comment: You may have to toggle the Character & Paragraph panels in order for them to appear.  They weren't displayed by default for me, even when having the Text tool selected.

Comment: For me I played with the AV <--> setting and that worked.

Comment: @Gnoupi, There seems to be a limit of the line height to 72 pt. How do we get a larger line height?

Comment: @Pacerier - add one empty line and modulate from that? Other than that, I don't really have an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to increase(or change) space after the paragraph(s):

[image]